# Can I artificially restrict a user's sql permissions to be read only for any connections from my application?

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I'm having an issue regarding the security of an application that I'm building... It's a wrapper for a crystal report viewer that provides users with some additional functionality.

There are many internal users with the ability to create/modify Crystal Reports. I've done some tests, and for an application that deals so intimately with connecting to various data sources, it doesn't seem to care the least bit about doing so safely. There is nothing stopping me from modifying an existing crystal report that everyone trusts to make it into something malicious and harmful. All it takes is an added command table with the following sql:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_Employees; SELECT FROM tbl_Employees;
```

In fact, you can do anything in a crystal report that the user has permissions to do... so long as it ends with a select. Which leads me to my question: Is there any way for me to ensure that my application limits any connections to our sql server to just selects? I can't temporarily modify user credentials, and I can't use a single read only account because I still need to limit the user to their normal permissions (i.e. which databases they can query).

I'm not very hopeful, as nothing that I've read has led me to believe that I can restrict connections in such a manner.

On the other hand, most of the people making the reports could take a much more direct approach to destroying our data, if they were so inclined... but I hardly think that that is a good excuse not to do my best to ensure that my application is as safe as I can make it. I just can't seem to find any viable answers.

Comment: how is crystal connecting to the db? with the user's own permissions, or with its own dedicated account?

Comment: These users could also delete/destroy data using a query tool (SSMS, WinSQL, whatever). Can you get the DBA to take an interest in that notion?

Comment: @Marc B: Crystal Reports uses the user's permissions. I can build my application in such a way that I intercept and handle the report's request for data using a special user account, but I still need to restrict the results to the user's permissions. My only though is to mirror each user with a read-only version, but that would be a maintenance hell, and just plain ugly.

Comment: @David: The sql user accounts have precisely the permissions they require to accomplish their job functions. In many cases, this includes update/deletes. Every work environment requires some level of trust... but a user with just read only permissions can modify a report to delete records, and just wait for a user with the right permissions to come along and run it.

Comment: Could the application do some pattern matching on the query string and refuse to run the report if the query string doesn't start with "SELECT" (or if anything but "SELECT" appears after a semicolon)?

Comment: Crystal Reports can map tables directly (it builds it's own select statement) or the user can use a command to write their own sql. It's the latter bit that is open to attack, and yes, I can extract these commands from the report (For anyone interested in how, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140665/how-can-i-retrieve-the-sql-select-statement-used-in-an-crystal-report/8145622#8145622) The problem is that some reports do things like insert into temp tables, so I can't match that and restrict it. The same could potentially be said for other data transformations...

Answer (score 1):

**You should use a read-only account for reporting purposes--no exceptions!**  Give the account access to SELECT rights to tables and views and EXEC rights functions (exposed via synonyms).  Avoid procedures, if possible--they are usually unnecessary and you may inadvertently give users access to procedures that modify the database (an experience a client of mine encountered).

** edit **

I guess it depends also on how the sensitive data is represented.

You would add a row-level filter to the record-selection formula when the report is run.

If the sensitive data is contained in a small number of tables, you could use role-based security (user added to group; roles assigned to group).

If you are using BusinessObjects Enterprise, you could use a Universe to control data security.  BusinessViews are also an option; they are the original (before BusinessObjects and SAP) semantic layer that supports dynamic/cascading parameters, but they have been slated for obsolescence.

Comment: How do I then ensure that Johnny can't create a report that views sensitive information he shouldn't be seeing? I still need to ensure that individual users are still limited to their permitted databases. One read-only account won't cut it... and making a read-only version of each user would be a maintenance nightmare...

Comment: How are your reports deployed?  Via your application?  BusinessObjects Enterprise?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm putting this as an answer because I still can't post global comments, but this is an idea that can help you in some way (i hope).

I don't have lots of experience in SQL Server as I do in Oracle DBs. In Oracle DBs, for each user you have their own space. Each user can only read and modify DB objects (tables and other things) that are within its space (Schema), no exceptions. Then you can grant access for each user to a specific object outside his own schema, and this is a qualified access (like "read-only", "just update", etc). To make it easier to maintain those grants, you can create roles, which are basically a named group of grants that can be assigned to a specific user.

Ok, I'm pretty sure that nothing out of this is new for you, but my point is: to acomplish what you're looking for, in an Oracle environment, you could use DB users for each user and control the access to information (tables) through that (very secure) controls.

I'm pretty sure that in SQL Server, aside from minor differences, you could do the same kind of strategy. Hope this leads you to some ideas on solving that...